# Multi level category navigation in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer, multi-level, categorization

I am currently working on an app that is the mobile version of an on-line store. The on-line store has a great number of products ,like 10 thousand already that keeps growing all the time. To facilitate navigation and browsing on the web we have as usual a multilevel category navigation. For example on of the main top categories may have like 4 sub-levels of categorization.  How can I implement this in android. `ExpandableListView`  doesn't really help me with this because it supports a two level categorization and not more. I am also familiar with implementing a `listView` Categorization in `NavigationDrawer` but for this i haven't found a solution yet.

Any suggestions will be more than welcome.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: No, not yet, I used the 'ExpandableListView' that provides two level categorization.